# Sentencia sql seleccionar entre registros

Tags: sql

Tengo la siguiente sentencia sql:

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM mensaje ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ' . $this_page_first_result . ',' . $results_per_page;
```

La cual me muestra los datos de la base de datos. Lo que quiero es que además de que como muestra ahora el listado por el id descendente, es seleccionar una serie de registros por id, por ejemplo entre el 60 y el 80. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

He incluido la siguiente sentencia pero no surte efecto:

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM mensaje ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT WHERE id BETWEEN '31' AND '33'
```

Gracias y un saludo

Comment: Que tipo de dato es id? varchar, numeric, character...?

Comment: El tipo del dato del id auto incrementable es INT

Comment: Entiendo, gracias! Probaste ya con sacar las comillas, es decir en ves de `BETWEEN '31' AND '33'` poner `BETWEEN 31 AND 33`?

Comment: Quita el limit y pon el order by al final

Comment: Para mi con lo que dije yo y David JP tiene que funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Yo cambiaría el orden de las clausulas.

```
SELECT * FROM mensaje **WHERE id BETWEEN 60 AND 80** *ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT*
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigos por la ayuda. Ya esta funcionando perfectamente. Saludos